# AWS CloudFormation template adding IP address to Route 53 record, not URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the Amazon Web Services CloudFormation solution to create a DB (RDS), some servers (ElasticBeanstalk), and add some DNS entries (Route 53).

The template I use for this is running just fine, and all services are being created as required with the exception of the DNS (CNAME) record.

To grab the value of the CNAME record to add, I'm using `Fn::GetAtt`, and grabbing the `EndpointURL` of an ElasticBeanstalk object.  The [Amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) suggest that this shold grab -

> The URL to the LoadBalancer for this environment.
>
> Example: awseb-myst-myen-132MQC4KRLAMD-1371280482.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

However, the issue is that it's instead grabbing the IP address.  Because of this, the CNAME is failing.

Has anyone come across this issue before, and if so, what was the work around?

Here is the relevant excerpt from my template -

```
"RecordSetObject": {
  "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
  "Properties": {
    "HostedZoneId": "Q1W2E3R4T5Y6U7",
    "Name": {
      "Fn::Join": [
        "",
        [
          { "Ref": "EnvironmentName" },
          "-",
          { "Ref": "ApplicationName" },
          ".",
          "super.secret.url",
          "."
        ]
      ]
    },
    "ResourceRecords": [
      {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "EBObjectName",
          "EndpointURL"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Type": "CNAME",
    "TTL": "300"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out @david-gard? I'm having the same issue and can't find anyone else reporting this.

Comment: Nope, no solution unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! Will post an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: For clarity of anyone else to come across this, I think the issue is with CloudFormation's Elastic Beanstalk support, as I'm trying to expose the domain as an export (no CloudFront/Route53) and seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this only occurs when the Beanstalk environment type is '[single instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html#single-instance-environ)', i.e. when there is something like the following in the CloudFormation template:

```
{
    "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
    "OptionName": "EnvironmentType",
    "Value": "SingleInstance"
}
```

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) state:

> In a single-instance environment, the elasticbeanstalk.com subdomain resolves to an Elastic IP address attached to the instance running your application.

It seems odd that `{ "Fn::GetAtt": [ "EBObjectName", "EndpointURL" ]}` doesn't just return the elasticbeanstalk.com subdomain, which is perhaps a CloudFormation issue.